# Electrical socket want to buy a usb plug table lamp can it work with 220 to 240 volts

Tags: electrical

I want to buy a table lamp which comes with a usb plug.  Can this plug work in a country with 240 voltage sockets

Comment: USB is around 5 volts.  Is lamp made to run off USB or has a USB socket?  If only socket, is lamp 120v or 240v?  Ad for lamp should say.

Comment: Maybe you should supply a link to the lamp you're asking about, as your question is very unclear.

Comment: Buy a table lamp that is made for 240V.  80% of the world lives in 240V territory, including all developed countries except the US, Canada and Japan... so you should have *more* selection not less.  If the lamp is made for 240V, feel free to put your country's 240V plug on it.

Comment: Are USB-output wall adapters not a thing where you live?